# Trying to find row sums in R using dplyr, then filter out columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rowsum

So I thought this would be a little simpler but it's proving not to be the case.

I would like to get the row total of each row and filter the rows that have a row total not equal to 0, but since the first column is an identifier I need to only sum all but the first (using dplyr). Additionally, any column = 0 should be filtered out as well.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[2:.N])) %>%
  filter(Total != 0)
```

But i get the following error:

```
Error in 2:.N : argument of length 0
```

Here's the df:

```
df <- structure(list(Sequence = c(12, 600, 620, 630, 660, 770, 780, 
800, 6900), Period_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3), Period_2 = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4), Period_3 = c(23232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -103), Period_4 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_5 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_6 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_7 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_8 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_9 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_10 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_11 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_12 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_13 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_14 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_15 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_16 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_17 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_18 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_19 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_20 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_21 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_22 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_23 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_24 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_25 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_26 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_27 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_28 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_29 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_30 = c(NA, -1170303.36, -449711.72, 
0, 0, -30548246.94, -42287004.62, 2.98818, NA), Period_31 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_32 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_33 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_34 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 497378.9, 191127.5, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_35 = c(NA, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_36 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
NA), Period_37 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_38 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_39 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_40 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_41 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_42 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_43 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_44 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_45 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_46 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_47 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_48 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_49 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_50 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_51 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_52 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_53 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_54 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_55 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_56 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_57 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_58 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_59 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_60 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_61 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_62 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_63 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_64 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_65 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_66 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_67 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_68 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_69 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_70 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_71 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_72 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_73 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_74 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_75 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_76 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_77 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_78 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_79 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_80 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_81 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_82 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_83 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_84 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_85 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_86 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_87 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_88 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_89 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_90 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_91 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_92 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_93 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_94 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_95 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_96 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_97 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_98 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_99 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_100 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_101 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_102 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_103 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_104 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_105 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_106 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_107 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_108 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_109 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_110 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_111 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_112 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_113 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_114 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_115 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_116 = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), Period_117 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), Period_118 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've looked into a couple ways of doing this but I cannot get it to work without an error, because I am excluding the first column. The column filter behaves similarly as well, that is, any column with a total equal to 0 should be removed.

Comment: Did you meant `df %>%
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[2:ncol(df)])) %>% filter(Total != 0)`. The `.N` is used in `data.table` context, returns the number of rows

Comment: ```
Error: Positive column indexes in `[` must match number of columns:
* `.data` has 119 columns
```

Comment: It's the first time I see `>%>` for the pipe symbol.

Comment: @RuiBarradas lol oops

Comment: With your dput, I am not getting any error.  If you have groupeed it `df %>% ungroup. %>%  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[2:ncol(df)])) %>% filter(Total != 0)`

Comment: @akrun data is not grouped, and the dput is identical

Comment: Error: Positive column indexes in `[` must match number of columns:
* `.data` has 119 columns
* Position 119 equals 120
* Position 120 equals 121
* Position 121 equals 122
* Position 122 equals 123

Comment: I used `dplyr_0.8.3`

Comment: With the data provided, `Total` is always not zero.

Comment: that is correct however i am building for future cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(janitor)

# Drop rows where the row total is 0
# adorn_totals() skips the first column, assuming it's an identifier
out <- df %>%
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col")) %>%
  filter(Total != 0)

# Then drop columns where the column total is zero
out[, unlist(out[nrow(out),]) != 0]
```

I shortened your input data to:

```
df <- data.frame(Sequence = c(12, 600, 620, 630, 660, 770, 780, 
                                  800, 6900), Period_1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3), Period_2 = c(2, 
                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4), Period_3 = c(23232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                          0, -103), Period_4 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA))
```